# Using Objection JS How can I select specific columns with withGraphFetched

Tags: mysql, orm, objection.js

I have this question:
How can I indicate which columns I want get from database with the `withGraphFetched` method, I have a `BelongsToOneRelation` and I want exclude some columns, this is my model:

```
module.exports = class ProveedorModel extends Model {

  ...

  static relationMappings = {
    empresa: {
      relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
      modelClass: EmpresaModel,
      join: {
        from: 'proveedor.empresa_id',
        to: 'empresa.id'
      }
    }
  };

  ...

}
```

and in my controller I have this:

```
const payload = await ProveedorModel.query().withGraphFetched('empresa');
```

but table `empresa` has to many columns which I won't, so how can I filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can specify `filter` property for your relationship

```js
class Person extends Model {
  static relationMappings = {
    pets: {
      relation: Model.OneToManyRelation,
      modelClass: Animal,
      filter: query => query.select('id', 'ownerId', 'name'),
      join: {
        from: 'Person.id',
        to: 'Animal.ownerId'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ref: https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/issues/70#issuecomment-175143072

Just wondering why objection doesn't query only columns mapped in `tableMetadata` (https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/static-methods.html#static-tablemetadata) when used `withGraphFetched` like it does for `withGraphJoined`

Alternatively, you could map just the properties you want with parsedatabasejson
(https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/instance-methods.html#parsedatabasejson) but your SQL query will bring them all.